# Stack - gcc ISO C99 compiler support missing

Tags: haskell, gcc, ghc, haskell-stack

After moving the contents of my old computer to a new one, I tried to continue working on a haskell project with Stack, but stack build commands no longer work. The initial issue was with the user directory having a space in it, which I fixed. Now the problem seems to be that the gcc compiler claims not to support ISO C99. I tried uninstalling by removing the stack directories as recommended and reinstalling, but the same error happens.

Here's what I get:

```
$ stack build --verbose

.......................
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.540986: [debug] GHC build  : x86_64-apple-darwin
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.541096: [debug] GHC host   : x86_64-apple-darwin
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.541205: [debug] GHC target : x86_64-apple-darwin
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.541270: [debug] LLVM target: x86_64-apple-darwin
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.545717: [debug] checking for path to top of build tree... /Users/derekmaffett/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.3.temp/ghc-8.4.3
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.546706: [debug] checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.559229: [debug] checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.560560: [debug] checking for gfind... no
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.561585: [debug] checking for find... /usr/bin/find
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.569598: [debug] checking whether ln -s works... yes
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.571630: [debug] checking for gsed... /usr/local/bin/gsed
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.663057: [debug] checking XCode version... 9.4.1
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.669808: [debug] configure: XCode version component 1: 9
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.669935: [debug] configure: XCode version component 2: 4
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.671086: [debug] checking for gcc... gcc
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.836599: [debug] checking whether the C compiler works... yes
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.836730: [debug] checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.879977: [debug] checking for suffix of executables...
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.940808: [debug] checking whether we are cross compiling... no
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:14.980289: [debug] checking for suffix of object files... o
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:15.015762: [debug] checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:15.053195: [debug] checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:15.112028: [debug] checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:15.181570: [debug] checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:15.785414: [debug] checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... unsupported
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
2018-07-29 18:51:15.785615: [debug] configure: error: C99-compatible compiler needed
@(src/Stack/Setup.hs:1097:54)
Configuring GHC ...
Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /Users/docr/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.2.2.temp/ghc-8.2.2/configure --prefix=/Users/docr/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.2.2/
Run from: /Users/docr/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.2.2.temp/ghc-8.2.2/
```

Stack version

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I installed Stack with the following method, as recommended.

```
curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
```

Comment: I wonder if it could be related at all to xcode? It seems that it may actually be what installs `gcc`, and the version automatically installed is past the most recent stable 8.x release.